# Aliasing with variables in bash profile

Tags: vim, alias, bash

Here's a very simple question about my vim bash profile. 
I would like to create an alias where I type "activate (variable)", and my virtual env immediately gets activated by running this command:

```
$ source foldername/bin/activate
```

As you can see, foldername will be the variable in this case, so I figured, I should write a function instead of a static one liner to set this alias. I tried something likes this:

```
activate(something){
    source something/bin/activate
}
```

Ideally, what I would like is to type:

```
$ activate f1
```

and this command gets run:

```
$ source f1/bin/activate
```

It would also be nice to have a default. So calling "activate" would also work. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't `virtualenvwrapper` provide a `workon` command? It automatically detects your virtual envirionments and all you have to do is `workon name_of_env`, even autocompletion with tab key works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update your shell environment, using a function like this:

```
function activate () {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        # no arguments passed to the function (default case)
        source f1/bin/activate
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        # one argument passed to the function
        source "$1"/bin/activate # argument value read from $1
    fi
}
```

Comment: Would this happen to be Perl, and could you also explain what each of those symbols mean? thanks!

Comment: @jasonadams: Heh, Perl's not the only language that uses non-letter symbols.

Comment: @jason adams: oh, you scared me! Check the updated answer.